# maximize perimeter of triangle inscribed in square with given side length

Tags: geometry

If I'm given the side length of a square and I am to inscribe a triangle in the square then how would I place the points to maximize the perimeter of the triangle?  I would also like to know how this would work for rectangles.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By a compactness argument, a maximizing triangle exists. Hence we need only look for constellations that cannot be improved.

If any vertex is not on the boundary of the rectangle, we can translate it outward along its angular bisector and note that this increases the perimeter (in fact, both of its edges become longer). Hence we may assume that all vertices are on the rectangle boundary (if that was not clear beforehand).

Consider the image below where at least one triangle vertex $C$ is not a rectangle.
By reflecting the rectangle along the edge $C$ is on, we arrive at the image below with $B'$ the reflected image of $B$. Let $\ell$ be the length of polyline $ACB'$ (and at the same time of polyline $ACB$). The locus of all points $X$ with length of $AXB'$ being $\ell$ is an ellipse with focal points $A,B'$. Any point inside the ellipse (for example the intersection of the dotted line with the rectangle edge) leads to shorter length, any point outside to longer length. In the image, $C$ is between the right end  vertex of the rectangle edge and the intersection of the (dotted) line $AB'$ with the edge. As the interior of the ellipse is convex, we conclude the right end of the edge is outside the ellipse and leads to a longer polyline and hence a longer perimeter.

[image]

We conclude that a maximizing triangle has all its vertices at vertices of the rectangle. Each such triangle has the same perimeter ($a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$) and hence is a maximizer.